# Source block html export show block on hover

Tags: org-export, html, css, org-reveal

I am working on a document that has multiple questions and answers to that question in a source block. Simplified example is as follows:

- Q1. (a+b)^2

```
#+begin_center
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 
#+end_center
```

After exporting the document to `html`, I'd like to be able to see the questions by default and reveal the answer block ONLY when I hover over the question (or something close, like click of a button on the source block).

I have come across docs on how to achieve hide/show behavior in org-reveal (presentations). Another example is [special-blocks-extras](https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/#Folded-Details) but got nowhere as it didn't make any difference to the html output!

Is there a simple way to achieve what I want in plain `html` export? Can this be achieved with custom `style, css`? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is put together hastily with information from [`HTML <details> Tag`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp).

I know nothing about `HTML`or `CSS`.  So, don't quote me on this reply :-P

To get the `details` tag you need `#+html_doctype: html5` and `#+options: html5-fancy:t` option.

To get this

[image: details block using stock HTML exporter]

export the following snippet to `HTML`  (You don't need any 3rd-party packages)

```
#+begin_details
#+begin_summary
(a+b)^2
#+end_summary

a^2 + 2ab + b^2
#+end_details

#+options: html-link-use-abs-url:nil html-postamble:nil
#+options: html-preamble:t html-scripts:nil html-style:t
#+options: html5-fancy:t tex:t
#+html_doctype: html5
#+html_container: div
#+html_content_class: content
#+description:
#+keywords:
#+html_link_home:
#+html_link_up:
#+html_mathjax:
#+html_equation_reference_format: \eqref{%s}
#+html_head:
#+html_head_extra:
#+subtitle:
#+infojs_opt:
#+creator: <a href="https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/">Emacs</a> 29.0.50 (<a href="https://orgmode.org">Org</a> mode 9.5.3)
#+latex_header:

#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>

#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: details > summary {
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   padding: 4px;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   cursor: pointer;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: }
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: details > p {
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   background-color: #eeeeee;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   padding: 4px;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   margin: 1em;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #bbbbbb;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: }

#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: summary > p {
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   background-color: #00ff00;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   padding: 4px;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   margin: 0;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #bbbbbb; display: inline;
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: }

#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: </style>
```

---

FWIW, you can search for `details` in this repo https://github.com/alhassy/org-special-block-extras --- there is a search box on the top left right next to the cat logo --- and I get a hit at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alhassy/org-special-block-extras/208762b007eefaaa2ba200d426583fe9e99e4afa/org-special-block-extras.org. Search for `EmacsConf 2020 Abstract` in the this `org` file and try to correlate it with the corresponing `EmacsConf 2020 Abstract` in the `HTML` file https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/.

If I were you I would just start with that `org` file and strip it down to the `#+begin_details ... #+end_details` tag and go from there.

My guess is

```
#+begin_details Question
Answer
#+end_details
```

is what you need if you are using `org-special-block-extras`.

I hope the information here will get you started in the right direction ...